# Como Hicieron para que el interprete de python se fusione con el símbolo del sistema de windows

Tags: python, c++

Estoy interesado en como funciona los interpretes por dentro y quiero crear el mío propio para decidir el estilo de sintaxis para los comandos y estoy usando PYTHON como inspiración.

Cuando abro el cmd escribo el comando python y el cmd se fusiona con python y permite ingresar operaciones matemáticas y código con la sintaxis de python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hicieron para que se puedan fusionar, porque los programas que yo hago en C++ los puedo llamar desde el cmd y solo muestra la salida stdout pero nunca se funden

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe de llevar una especie de bucle para ir recibiendo comandos son las primeras suposiciones que hago y debe estar a la espera el stdin o algo así.

Comment: sabes en que esta basado el interprete de python?

Comment: Solamente sé que python esta hecho en C++ y que funciona ejecutando scripts o invocándolo desde el cmd. Esa invocación es la que quiero conocer como se hizo

Comment: El interprete de python esta echo en C, lo que al final hace un interprete es leer texto plano e ir transformándolo o a bytecodes para luego ser transformado a instrucciones maquina

Comment: al ejecutar el comando `python programa.py` el interprete que usa es *Cpython* tambien existe otro que es nativo de python llamado *Pypi*, al igual existe otro llamado *Jython* el cual esta hecho en Java, etc.  y así existen múltiples interpretes

Comment: Lo que se es que se ejecuta de diferentes modos y el que me interesa es" To run the stdin input using a shell pipe"

Comment: bien!, si sabes lo que quieres, ¿por que no investigas?

Comment: Hombre Chris tampoco le maltrates tanto jajaja, esta interesante su pregunta por lo menos la parte querer crear un comando cmd custom para su programa (es eso no?) aqui puedes encontrar info al respecto del sitio en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181709/custom-commands-in-windows-command-prompt

Por lo demás eso de crear un super interprete pues si esta jodido, lo que te queda es revisar el source de python y rezar porque halla documentación al respecto...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no hay ningún tipo de *fusión*. Un interprete de comandos es un tipo particular de programa que acepta una entrada y busca en esta *interpretar* los comandos que recibe para ejecutar acciones dentro del programa, que generalmente emiten alguna salida.

Puedes programar tu propio interprete de comandos, lo que tienes que hacer es figurarte como mantener la interacción con el usuario en una interfaz que funcione de esta manera. Esencialmente es un ciclo infinito de pedir un comando, analizarlo/interpretarlo y ejecutarlo, hasta que se introduce un comando que termina con la ejecución del interprete (que suele ser `quit`/`exit` en inglés, o `salir` en español.

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo en un script de python, espero que captes la idea. Puedes hacer algo similar en una aplicación de consola en c++ o en cualquier lenguaje que soporte este tipo de aplicaciones.

```
while True:
    comando = input(">>>")
    if comando == "saludar":
        print("hola, ¡mucho gusto!")
    elif comando == "ayuda":
        print("comandos: ")
        print("  ayuda: muestra la ayuda")
        print("  salir: termina el interprete de comandos")
        print("  saludar: imprime un saludo")
    elif comando == "salir":
        break
    else:
        print("comando no reconocodio, escriba ayuda para obtener una lista de los comandos soportados")
```

Este sencillo interprete de comandos soporta solo tres comandos:

- `ayuda`: te muestra la ayuda de los comandos
- `salir`: termina la ejecución del interprete de comandos
- `saludar`: emite un saludo

Si lo ejecutas desde la línea de comandos del sistema, parecerá que se *ha fusionado* con el simbolo del sistema (por usar tus propias palabras).

Ahora, el interprete no tiene por qué ser tan simple... puedes tener un analizador léxico/sintáctico para la entrada, una serie de mecanismos para ejecutar comandos internos y externos al interprete, como hace el cmd.exe, o todo un lenguaje de programación, como hace python. El límite es tu imaginación, habilidades y conocimiento.